# How to drag drop an angularJS element using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, angular6, angular-dragdrop

I need to drag an element from one location to other using the selenium webdriver for angula6 element

I have tried using

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();

but it does not work.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

String obj = "/html[1]/body[1]/app-root[1]/app-frame[1]/div[1]/adsvalu-create-sales-target[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]";
String obj1 = "/html[1]/body[1]/app-root[1]/app-frame[1]/div[1]/adsvalu-create-sales-target[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]";

WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj));
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj1));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
```

There is no error but the drag and drop action is not happening

Comment: Relevant HTML please?

Comment: @DebanjanB the xpaths are added

Comment: First, ensure that selectors are valid. Second, why double from and to variables?

Comment: @kirill.z I ensure that the selectors are valid. Also corrected the object names

Comment: @AbhijitD 1. try without build 2. try split actions with sleep() like (new Actions(driver)).clickAndHold(dragable).moveToElement(dropable) --> sleep() --> .release(dragable).build() --> sleep() etc. because too fast test execution. 3. try to use https://github.com/storenth/drag-mock